# Is a primitive permutation group, indecomposable?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Is a [primitive permutation group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_permutation_group), [indecomposable](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Directly_indecomposable_group)?

Comment: No. There is a primitive action of $\operatorname{PSL}(2,7)\times\operatorname{PSL}(2,7)$ of degree $168$, that I found by computer search.

Comment: @James: You're right, with GAP `PrimitiveGroup(168,1)` is   `PSL(2, 7)^2`. How did you find it? Is it the first? Did you write a function `IsIndecomposable`?

Comment: It's not the first, because `PrimitiveGroup(60,1)` gives `Alt(5)^2`. Is it the first example? It seems that for a simple group $G$, the diagonal subgroup $D$ of $G×G$ is core-free and maximal (i.e primitive action of $G×G$ on the cosets $(G×G)/D$). Conversely, if $G \times G$ admits a primitive action, is $G$ simple?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux You should look up the O'Nan-Scott Theorem, which gives a precise description of all finite primitive permutation groups. In particular, for finite nonabelian simple group $S$, the action of $S$ on the cosets of a diagonal subgroup is a decomposable primitive group. I think these are probably the only examples, but I am not totally sure!

Comment: The answer to your question, if $G \times G$ admits a primitive action then is $G$ (nonabelian) simple is yes. You just need to prove that any maximal subgroup of $G \times G$ contains a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: See: [Classification of the decomposable primitive permutation groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/914095/84284)