# Classification of the decomposable primitive permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

It is seen [in comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913510/84284) that the diagonal subgroup of the finite group $G \times G$ is core-free maximal iff $G$ is a nonabelian simple group.
This gives examples of decomposable primitive permutation groups. Are there others examples?

**Question**: What's the classification of the decomposable primitive permutation groups?

Comment: *Generalization*: [Classification of indecomposable inclusions $(H⊂G)$ with $G$ decomposable](http://mathoverflow.net/q/179745/34538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the only decomposable finite primitive permutation groups are groups $S \times S$ with $S$ a nonabelian simple group, acting on the cosets of a diagonal subgroup.

A decomposable group has at least two minimal normal subgroups. According to the O'Nan-Scott Theorem, the only type of finite primitive permutation group $G$ with more than one minimal normal subgroups, has exactly two such, $M$ and $N$, with $M \cong N \cong S^k$ for some nonabelian simple group $S$ and $k \ge 1$.

In the primitive action, on a  finite set $X$, $M$ and $N$ are both regular normal subgroups. But then $N$ is the centralizer of $N$ in ${\rm Sym}(X)$ and vice versa, and hence also in $G$. But if $G$ is decomposable, then $M$ and $N$ must be subgroups of the two direct factors, and so $G = M \times N$. Then $G$ is primitive only when $k=1$.

Comment: Thank you! Can your argument be extended for the generalization added?

Comment: I don't know what an indecomposable inclusion is. (You might have defined this in another question, but I think I found the definition too complicate and gave up!)

Comment: The notion of *indecomposable inclusion* (of groups) is a natural generalization of the notion of *indecomposable group*. First, two inclusions are equivalent ($\sim$) if they produce the same transitive permutation group (up to conjugation) via the action on cosets. Now $(H \subset G)$ is *indecomposable* if $(H \subset G) \sim (H_1 \times H_2 \subset G_1 \times G_2)$ (with $(H_i \le G_i)$) implies that  $\exists i$ with $(H_i \subset G_i)$ trivial (i.e. $H_i = G_i$). Examples: the maximal inclusions. It's not clear to me that we obtain an equivalent definition if we replace $\sim$ by $=$.

Comment: I've posted the generalization [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/179745/34538).